# How can we correct or suppress CA0503 and CA0505 messages from Code Analysis in Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: code-analysis, visual-studio-2012, static-code-analysis

When I run Code Analysis on a fairly simple project, I immediately get "CA0503 Issue Running Code Analysis" and "CA0505 Issue Running Code Analysis" violations.  [The CA0503 documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA0503%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) says, "The property is deprecated. Use the superseding property." However, it does not point at a superseding property, how to deal with the error, or how to suppress it.  Apparently, this is a hidden Microsoft ruleset and you can't just turn the rule off.

[The CA0505 documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461609.aspx) similarly states, "The deprecated property will be ignored because the superceding property is defined."  It goes on to say, "Warning CA505 is generated when both the specified deprecated and superceding code analysis properties contain values in a project or build configuration file. To resolve this issue, remove the deprecated property."

Text searches throughout the solution for either CA0503 or CA0505 return nothing.  However, a search for "CodeAnalysisRules" finds a line in each of my two project files:

> <CodeAnalysisRules>-Microsoft.Design#CA2210</CodeAnalysisRules>

No corresponding line for "CodeAnalysisRuleSet" is found by a similar text search.

Has anyone else encountered this and perhaps found a way either to correct or suppress these messages?

Comment: What properties is it complaining about?  What are the exact diagnostics emitted by the analysis?

Comment: Well, I gave the information but here is the Code Analysis output:  "CA0505 Issue Running Code Analysis CA0505 : The CodeAnalysisRules property will be ignored because the CodeAnalysisRuleSet property is defined. [Errors and Warnings] (Global) 
" and "CA0503 Issue Running Code Analysis CA0503 : The CodeAnalysisRules property is deprecated. Use the CodeAnalysisRuleSet property instead. [Errors and Warnings] (Global) 
".  That's all the information Microsoft gives to me.

Comment: Note that this is a fresh installation of the Visual Studio 11 Beta and I have not had time to do my usual tweaking; so, it's VS11 basically "out of the box."

Comment: `<CodeAnalysisRules>` has been superseded by `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`.  If you change your project file to use `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`, the warning should go away.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when upgrading a Visual Studio 2008 project to Visual Studio 2013. During the upgrade, an error popped up about not being able to add a `.ruleset` file due to what I will call 'special TFS source control reasons'.

Pre-upgrade, my project file (in my case a `.csproj` file) contained a `<CodeAnalysisRules>` element. This contained a huge string relating to code analysis rules for the project. Post-upgrade, my project file's `CodeAnalysisRules` element was unchanged, but a `Migrated rules for [project name].ruleset` file was created in the project directory.

To fix it, I:

1. Added the `.ruleset` file to the project (it may already have been added for you, mine was just dumped in the project directory).
2. Unloaded the project.
3. Updated the `.csproj` file by removing the `<CodeAnalysisRules>` element altogether, and adding in its place `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>Migrated rules for [project name].ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` or whatever the name of the `.ruleset` file is.
4. Reloaded the project.

I assume during a successful upgrade that Visual Studio parses the contents of the old `<CodeAnalysisRules>` element, creates a `.ruleset` file based upon it, and links that to the project. It doesn't always work I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated a solution from a previous Visual Studio and you had defined a centralized rules file. You need to [manually remove](http://xtrmdevtips.blogspot.be/2011/01/annoying-static-code-analysis-errors-in.html) it from your projects.

Answer (score 0):

While running the code analysis, your project file gets updated  automatically. There will be an entry added - CodeAnalysisRules. This is the reason for this warning. I think, you need to configure in such a way that the element CodeAnalysisRules does not come in the project file.